# Calculate based on formula in Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My table contains data

```
pk |  formula    |    OP_NME
---+-------------+---------
 1 |   x*10      |  A
 2 |   (X+Y)*10  |  B
```

based on the formula and input value for x and y, I need to give output.

Eg: i get x=10, Y=20 as input, i need to give output as A=100 and B=300.

Comment: Are you any front-end for this?

Comment: What did you try so far? Why not use a database view?

Comment: Data in this table will be inserted from application. I am asked to write a SP which takes the Input values like PK and value of X and Y.

Answer (score 4):

This may not be a comprehensive answer, but may help you well

```
Declare @tab table (pk int,formula varchar(100),OP_NME varchar(10),X int)
Insert into @tab values(1,'x*10','A',Null),(2,'(X+Y)*10','B',Null)
Declare @result table (id int identity(1,1),[values] int,pk int)

Declare @s int = 1,
        @e int = (Select max(pk) From @tab),
        @sql varchar(max) = 'Declare @x int = 10,@y int = 20  ',
        @sql2 varchar(max)

While @s <= @e
Begin
    Select @sql2 = @sql + 'Select(' + Replace(Replace(formula,'x','@x'),'y','@y') + ')' From @tab Where pk = @s
    Insert into @result ([values])
    Exec(@sql2)

    Update @result
    Set pk = @s
    Where id = @@identity

Set @s = @s + 1
End

Select T.pk,T.formula,R.[values]
from @result R
join @tab T On R.pk = T.pk
```

Run the SQL in the Management studio and see the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, I am using the part of the above code.